# How to customize jquery dialog like facebook user details

Tags: jquery, facebook, dialog

when we hover the mouse on any facebook user link then a dialog appear with progress image and after few minute content shown but when content shown then dialog height & width increase based on content height & width.

this way we can load data into dialog

```
jQuery('#dialog').load('path to my page').dialog('open');
```

but guide me how to change the above code which will initially show a small dialog with busy image and when `load method` will finish loading data then dialog height & width will increase as per content height & width including height & width mention also in css style.

looking for idea with sample code. thanks

Comment: ..but what have you tried and/or looked into so far?

Comment: i am looking for idea that how to build hover dialog like facebook.

Comment: There are many ideas out there with code examples/demos just by googling or checking Facebook dev section.. this question is **primarily opinion-based**. _"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_